# What's UserDataTask in UWP?

Tags: uwp

The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.userdatatasks lacks sample.
Is it about `Windows Task Scheduler` or `WinRT` background tasks or `Cortana` tasks?

Comment: None of the above. It's for apps to create "To-Do" lists, [similar to these](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-tasks-and-to-do-items-45A94E7B-A4EE-46EA-9823-C3423C0EAB8E). The `UserData` prefix is generally used to mean "Things a personal information manager (like Outlook) might do." It includes things like contacts, email, calendars, events, meetings, and tasks.

Comment: Actually, that's just what I am doing for myself & after a few iterations, I may publish it. So the flow should be UserTaskManager.GetforUser(UserPicker()).RequestStoreAsync() to get the UserDataTaskStore, am I headed in the right direction? Beyond that the docs feel intuitive for now.
Btw, I didn't intend to escalate this upto you so soon, thnx.

Comment: For my requirement, I'll get the user as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs.user#Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_LaunchActivatedEventArgs_User

Comment: That'll work. If you aren't writing a multi-user app, you can use `UserDataTaskManager.GetDefault()` as a shortcut.